# Object of syncronized list can't be changed from interface callback

Tags: java, android

Expected to be totally minusing.

I'm using method, which makes request to server in another thread :

```
    getGeocodingResults(finalDepartureUrl, new IVolleyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        handleVolleyResponse(jsonObject, order, 1);
                        OrdersFragment.syncedOrdersList.get(OrdersFragment.syncedOrdersList.indexOf(order)).setDeparturePoint(order.getDeparturePoint());
                        OrdersFragment.syncedOrdersList.set(OrdersFragment.syncedOrdersList.indexOf(order), order);

                });
```

onSuccess moght to be called in the main thread, and I set new value to the static syncronized list. Here is a declaration :

```
syncedOrdersList  = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(ordersList));
```

But when I check the same object after the callback execution, I see , that new value to the field wasn't setted - so the `departurePoint` filed is null.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Method, where I loop through all the items and call backgroung operation at each loop :

```
 public void addOrdersToMap(LinkedBlockingQueue<Order> list)
{
    if (ordersToDisplay != null)
        clearMap();
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        for (final Order order : list) {
            String finalDepartureUrl = Constants.URL_GEOCODING + getAddressUrlString(Constants.FLAG_ADDRESS_DEPARTURE,order);
            String finalDestinationUrl = Constants.URL_GEOCODING + getAddressUrlString(Constants.FLAG_ADDRESS_DESTINATION, order);
            getGeocodingResults(finalDepartureUrl, new IVolleyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    handleVolleyResponse(jsonObject, order, Constants.FLAG_ADDRESS_DEPARTURE);
                }
            });
            getGeocodingResults(finalDestinationUrl, new IVolleyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    handleVolleyResponse(jsonObject, order, Constants.FLAG_ADDRESS_DESTINATION);
                }
            });
               /*
                *  Log.i(TAG + " lat lng", a[0].toString());
                *  here the value of the setted field is null
                */
            }

    }

}
```

handleVolleyResponse is a method, where I parse the data and set the new value to the object's field :

```
 private void handleVolleyResponse(JSONObject jsonObject, Order order, int flag) {
  /* ... here is json data parsing */
    switch (flag) {
       case Constants.FLAG_ADDRESS_DEPARTURE:
      /* here is a point, where I set parsed value into the  object's field */
             OrdersFragment.syncedOrdersList.get(OrdersFragment.syncedOrdersList.indexOf(order)).setDeparturePoint(latLng);
        order.setDeparturePoint(latLng);
        setMarker();
        break;
  case Constants.FLAG_ADDRESS_DESTINATION:
    /* here is a point, where I set parsed value into the object's field */
        OrdersFragment.syncedOrdersList.get(OrdersFragment.syncedOrdersList.indexOf(order)).setDestinationPoint(latLng);

  order.setDestinationPoint(latLng);
  setMarker();
   break;
 }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html ? that way it's always synchronized without you having to worry about synchronisation of the data. Also keep in mind threads are fickle beings. I suggest you do a mylinkedlist.size() check on every thread loop to see if the value has been added.

Comment: Thank you. But, it seems to be that value can't be added. 
When I try 
 OrdersFragment.ordersQueue.put(order);
in the onSuccess method, the object can't added after the callback finished

Comment: Please post more code of both threads. I can't determine thread flow from your examples.

Comment: Michael, I've added, please check

Comment: Okay. so to recap and please correct me. You save Orders in the list. Then you get a callback from something and you wish to update the object within the list with a value from the callback?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: But... you are looking up the Order object by the Order object you have... you can just add the variable directly on the order object you already have and the reference in the list will update too. I would suggest replacing all your SynchronisedLists with the LinkedBlockingQueue for storing the Orders though. I suggest you read up about references http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174371&seqNum=4